# Filter Table format view - Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal-7

I'm looking for some help about "Custom View". I looked throw the internet but can't find it (maybe cause of my bad key words).

I created a custom view with a Table format. The goal is to display content (based on a content type) in a table.

I already have my content showing, I can reorganize rows by client/sector.. by clicking on the column header but now I'd like to :

- Filter result depending on the string in an input textfield
  and
- Filter result using a dropdown menu

I guess It's client side, but I'm a beginner in drupal so it's a bit hard to find out.
Here is what I'd like :
http://hpics.li/175e64e

Answer (score 0):

For the select filter, you should try using exposed filters in your view. In the filter section, add filter on the fields and expose them. If these fields are taxonomy reference fields it should work right away. Otherwise it depends : with entity reference I think [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) can be usefull.

With plain text fields it will be more difficult to get what you want (personnaly I give up on exposed filters when it becomes to complicated), but still possible with this approach and a bit of client side work.

The general idea is to create JSON view wich gets all differents values for a text field across the nodes, using [Views Data Source](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource) (or get all nodes with fields values then fetch unique values for each fields in javascript).

On client side, on the page load make an ajax call to this view to get an array of all possible values, then build your select list using this array, and then do a client side filtering (using for example the excellent [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)).

But in my opinion you need to take side : all with views and exposed filters (server side, can be hard and frustrating...) or all in JS (client side), mixing the two should result in a big mess...

For the plain text search box I would choose to work client side, Views won't be of any help I'm afraid.

You can also find good javascript plugins for table sorting / filtering like [Datatables](https://datatables.net/).

Good luck.